# Question about SimpleModal jQuery plugin -- possible to re-center after initial open?

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

my problem has to do with [the SimpleModal jQuery plugin](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/).  I have no problem opening the modal window, but once it opens it stays where it is [centered] on the screen, however its contents are changing, making it taller and therefore no longer centered.  Is there a simple way to realign it so it becomes centered again?

**EDIT:** I think it would help to explain my problem by showing two screenshots: [before](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/4051/modalbefore.gif) & [after](http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/1215/modalafter.gif) -- basically I am using jQuery's [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) & [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) functionality to hide the credit card form depending on whether the user is paying via cash/cheque or credit card.  Obviously with the credit card fields the height of the container is increased.

I tried adding `$("div#modal-element").setPosition()` in a callback element of slideUp/slideDown but to no avail -- in fact `setPosition()` is throwing a JS error because apparently the function doesn't exist.  I always tried adding the autoResize option and setting it to true.

Comment: I answered your question, deleted it, then edited it...but forgot to undelete it until now.

Let me know if it doesn't help solve your question. Nick Craver's answer would help too, unless you had autoPosition:false in the options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the SimpleModal is rigged to handle re-centering on window resize, the simplest method would be to trigger that event.  After your content changes, just call this:

```
$(window).resize();
```

Comment: @Nick - I think we are on the right path but for some reason this causes my modal box to stay where it is but add scrollbars

Comment: @Andrew G. Johnson - Unfortunately SimpleModal doesn't expose the diaog object (outside of it's callbacks), closest you can get to it's event is `$(window).trigger('resize.simplemodal');`

Answer (score 2):

If you are in one of the callbacks, you have access to all of the functions and properties - so you could call setPosition() to re-center the dialog. For example:

```
$(element).modal({
    onShow: function (dialog) {
        var modal = this;

        // do stuff and change the container dimensions

        modal.setPosition(); // re-center the container
    }
});
```

I haven't tested the code, but it should work.

HTH

Comment: @Eric - Can you have a quick look at my screenshots and see if you think this should work?  My code seems to think the setPosition() function doesn't exist

Comment: Did you send it to me? As long as you are calling it off of the 'this' in the callback, it should work...