# SimpleModal Jquery plugin position problem

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I have the same problem of this thread: [Question about SimpleModal jQuery plugin -- possible to re-center after initial open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480320/question-about-simplemodal-jquery-plugin-possible-to-re-center-after-initial-o)

I tried the possible solution, but no success. My page have a scrollbar and after I open the modal, I have some action that resize the div. But when the div exceed the window visible area, the exceeded content is hidden. When I scroll the page the modal stay on the same position!

Its works well on IE6, not no on IE8.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting [max-height and max-width](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) to keep the dialog from growing too large.  Then you may need to make sure that the styling for this div includes [overflow:scroll](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Example of a possible solution:

```
$('#modalContent').modal({
    onShow: function (dialog) {
        var sm = this;

        // bind click event to get ajax content
        $('.link', dialog.container[0]).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                ..., // your settings here
                success: function (data) {
                    dialog.data.html(data); // put the data in the modal
                    dialog.container.css({height:'auto', width:'auto'}); // reset the dimensions
                    sm.setContainerDimensions(); // resize and center modal

                    // if you want to focus on the content:
                    sm.focus();

                    // if you want to rebind the events
                    sm.unbindEvents();
                    sm.bindEvents();
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

I'm going to look into putting a resize function in SimpleModal, which would take care of most of these steps. Until then, this should work for you.

-Eric

Comment: The problem is that I resize de modal after click some element inside the modal. I will prepare some example and post here.